# How to count number of calls of function without a global variable?

Tags: c, function, global, function-call

I have an assignment with C language: this code is given to us, its idea is to count how many time a function is called:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
int call_counter; //global
void fun()
{  call_counter++;}
void main()
{
 fun();  fun();   fun();
 printf("function \"fun\" was called %d times",call_counter);
}
```

Then they asked us the following question: If the variable “ call_counter” was not global how and where you should declare it?

I tried to declare it as a static variable inside the main, but the value won't increases even if the function is called:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun()
{  call_counter++;}
void main()
{
static int call_counter = 0;
fun();  fun();   fun();
printf("function \"fun\" was called %d times",call_counter);
}
```

but the output is 0, I don't know how to adjust the code to solve this question
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have four options:

1. Use a global variable.
2. Pass a reference to a counter to the function and increase it inside the function.
3. Use a local `static` counter inside the function and return it each time.
4. Use a macro plus a local variable in the caller.

For option 2 you can do something like this:

```c
void foo(unsigned *count) {
    (*count)++;
    // do something
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned count = 0;
    foo(&count); foo(&count); foo(&count);
    // count is now 3
}
```

For option 3:

```c
unsigned foo(void) {
    static unsigned count;
    count++;
    // do something
    return count;
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned count;
    foo(); foo(); 
    count = foo();
    // count is now 3
}
```

For option 4:

```c
void foo(void) {
    // do something
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned count = 0;

#define FOO_COUNT() do { foo(); count++; } while (0)

    FOO_COUNT(); FOO_COUNT(); FOO_COUNT();
    // count is now 3
}
```

Or in a different more general way:

```c
#define FN_COUNT(fn, counter) do { (fn)(); (counter)++; } while (0)

void foo(void) {
    // do something
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned count = 0;
    FN_COUNT(foo, count); FN_COUNT(foo, count); FN_COUNT(foo, count);
    // count is now 3
}
```

Comment: In option two you need to pass (a pointer to) the counter to the function.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom whoops forgot it, thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much sir! I tried option 3 and it worked. this is my first semester dealing with C language so we didn't really get really deep with pointer and methods other than print, thus this one was the most suitable one to understand and submit. Really thank you sir

Answer (score 2):

C does not have any global variables; the C standard does not use “global” for anything related to identifiers. The closest thing it has is external linkage with file scope, in which identifiers in different translation units may refer to the same thing.

If you declare the counter with `static`, it will have internal linkage, and so it will not be global or external. If you declare it outside of and before any function, it will be visible from its declaration to the end of the translation unit:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int call_counter;

void fun()
{
    call_counter++;
}

int main(void)
{
    fun();
    fun();
    fun();
    printf("The function \"fun\" was called %d times.\n", call_counter);
}
```

### Supplement

Do not declare `main` with `void main()`. Use `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` (or otherwise as defined by your C implementation).

Comment: To my understanding a global variable is a variable which is declared outside any function. With this definition adding "static" doesn't unglobalize it.

Comment: In "The C Programming Language" global variables are mentioned in a few places.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: As I stated, “global” generally means [visible throughout the program](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_variable). Using `static` limits linkage to internal, precluding global visibility or linkage.

Comment: It's still a (static) global variable (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_(keyword)#Static_global_variable).

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: When you have a reference telling us how the poser of the assignment intended the term, let us know. I have given the meanings I used and the reasons, and they are reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is to return from a function an integer value equal to 1. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun( void )
{
    //...
    return 1;
}

int main( void )
{
    size_t call_counter = 0;

    call_counter += fun();  call_counter += fun();   call_counter += fun();

    printf( "function \"fun\" was called %zu times.\n", call_counter );
}
```

Or you could yourself count how many times the function is called like

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun( void )
{
    //...
}

int main( void )
{
    size_t call_counter = 0;

    ( ++call_counter, fun() );  ( ++call_counter, fun() ); ( ++call_counter, fun() );

    printf( "function \"fun\" was called %zu times.\n", call_counter );
}
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun( void )
{
    puts( "Hello World!" );
}

int main(void) 
{
    size_t call_counter = 0;

    ( ++call_counter, fun() );  
    ( ++call_counter, fun() ); 
    ( ++call_counter, fun() );

    printf( "function \"fun\" was called %zu times.\n", call_counter );
    
    return 0;
}

Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
function "fun" was called 3 times.
```

Or you could wrap the function call in a macro like for example

```
#define FUN_CALL( n  )  ( ++n, fun() )
```

and use it like

```
FUN_CALL( call_counter );
```

Comment: Thank you all so much, I tried option number 3 from one of the answers and it worked. I don't know how to deal with pointer since this is my very first semester taking C language so this solution is suitable for me. Thank you so much really